# Robocopy log file: Extra dir and an improbable match

Tags: robocopy, batch-file

I have executed the following command:

robocopy.exe    /E /ZB /COPY:DAT /R:5 /W:7 /TBD /NP /TEE /LOG:

The intended file was copied, along with some other files which had the exact same name and were residing in the folder beneath the source directory. but this appeared in the output:

### Options : /TBD /TEE /S /E /COPY:DAT /ZB /NP /R:5 /W:7

*EXTRA Dir        -1      \computer\path\to\file

New Dir          0         \computer\path\to\folder

New Dir          0          \computer\path\to\folder

New Dir          1          \computer\path\to\folder

New File      1.5 m      filename

### -OUTPUT TRIMMED-

```
            Total    Copied   Skipped  Mismatch    FAILED    Extras
 Dirs :        15        14         1         0         0         2
Files :         4         4         0         0         0         0
```

1. I understand the *EXTRA dir stands for: An “extra” file is present in destination but not source. Can anyone explain the -1?
2. two folders were copied to the destination, without either of them containing the file specified in the command, or the file name in the path. They were not empty in the source folder but were copied empty. Why were those folders copied?